# ActiveRecord::Migration.say_with_time() do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

When we should be use this in seed file.in rails framework Active record.

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.say_with_time() do
```

Comment: See documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#class-ActiveRecord::Migration-label-Controlling+verbosity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method takes a block and benchmark it. The time taken and affected number of rows is printed out.

Eg from rom the docs:

```
say_with_time "Reverting all service rates to nil." do 
  Service.update_all( :rate, nil )
end

# Output
-- Reverting all service rates to nil.
-> 0.3451s 
-> 2233 rows
```

Comment: method name is _nice_ :)